# What is the total number of nested loop execution?

Tags: loops, for-loop, nested-loops

**Q1 -** At the following double-nested loop what will be the final value in `m` if loop does for `n`.
Of course it is not desired to do loop and see what the `m` is! Since `n` can be very large!

```
m = 0
for i = 1 to n-2
   for j = i+1,n-1
       for k = j+1,n
           m += 1
```

**Q2 -** How did you find the answer? I mean what was the algorithm/technique that you used to solve the problem?

**Q3 -** What are your recommendation to solve similar problems?

---

Here is the answer that I was looking for:

**Answer:**

```
def ntn(n,k):
    """returns the number of iterations for k nested dependent loops(n)"""
    return long(np.prod(n-np.arange(k,dtype=float)) / 
                np.prod(np.arange(k,dtype=float)+1))
```

**example:**

```
>>> ntn(1000,4)
41417124750L

>>> ntn(1e20,3)
166666666666666650797607483335462097315368077619447843520512L
```

Comment: This is really a math question. `sum(1 ≤ i ≤ n-2) sum(i+1 ≤ j ≤ n-1) sum(j+1 ≤ k ≤ n) 1`. Next step is to consult your favorite discrete mathematics textbook. First recommendation for solving similar problems is to show up for your professor's office hours.

Comment: @everybody: I solved the problem and found the answer that I was looking for and put above in the question. It is in Python language. Feel free to use it anyway without restriction!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Answer:**

Combination formula is as follows:

[image: f]

can be used for this purpose.
In Python there is `comb()` function within `scipy` package which can be used too.
However the following solution is much more flexible and faster and the resulting digits are much longer.

```
import numpy as np

def ntn(n,k):
    """returns the number of iterations for k nested dependent loops(n)"""
    return long(np.prod(n-np.arange(k,dtype=float)) / 
                np.prod(np.arange(k,dtype=float)+1))
```

**Examples:**

```
>>> ntn(1000,4)
41417124750L

>>> ntn(1e20,3)
166666666666666650797607483335462097315368077619447843520512L
```

Answer (score 2):

Q3: Find a pattern to the question.

Q2: Assuming `n:=10`

Notice that `i` will loop from `1 to 8`

Therefore, `j` will loop from

```
2 to 9
3 to 9
...
9 to 9
```

Therefore, `k` will loop from

```
             loops                                        value             index
3 to 10, 4 to 10, 5 to 10, ..., 10 to 10          8 + 7 + 6 + ... + 1         8
         4 to 10, 5 to 10, ..., 10 to 10              7 + 6 + ... + 1         7
                  5 to 10, ..., 10 to 10                  6 + ... + 1         6
                           ...      ...                           ...       ...
                                10 to 10                            1         1
```

Notice the pattern here: if we start the index from the bottom number (1), to get the `m`th number in the sequence, you simply sum 1 through m.

Q1: You figure this one out on your own. Hint: it's a summation of summations...

Comment: The question was solved by the questioner and the answer can be found in the question.

Comment: @Cambium you misunderstood completely, as the answer you have made is out of box.